# How can I stop a Web Audio Script Processor and clear the buffer?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to stop a web audio script processor node from running, without disconnecting it.

My initial thought was to just set the "onaudioprocess" to "null" to stop it, but when I do this I hear a really short loop of audio playing. My guess is that the audio buffer is not being cleared or something and it's repeatedly playing the same buffer.

I tried some additional techniques like first setting the buffer channel array values all to 0, then setting the "onaudioprocess" to "null", this still produced a looping slice of audio instead of silence.

#### I have some code like the below (coffeescript)

```
context = new webkitAudioContext()
scriptProcessor = context.createScriptProcessor()

scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = (e)->
  outBufferL = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0)
  outBufferR = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(1)
  i = 0
  while i < bufferSize
    outBufferL[i] = randomNoiseFunc()
    outBufferR[i] = randomNoiseFunc()
    i++
  return null
return null
```

#### Then when I want to stop it

```
stopFunc1: ->
  scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = null
```

#### I also tried setting the buffer channel arrays to 0, then setting the callback to null

```
stopFunc2: ->
  scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = (e)->
    outBufferL = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0)
    outBufferR = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(1)
    i = 0
    while i < bufferSize
      outBufferL[i] = 0
      outBufferR[i] = 0
      i++
    scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = null
    return null
  return null
```

#### Both techniques result in a slice of audio that loops really fast, instead of no audio.

Is there a way to do this correctly or am I just thinking about it wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding...

But if you null out `onaudioprocess`, it won't stop playback immediately unless you just happen to hit it at the very end of the current buffer.

Let's say your `bufferSize` is 2048, and you happen to null out `onaudioprocess` half-way through the current buffer duration of 46ms (2048 / 44100 * 1000). You're still going to have the another 23ms of audio that's already been processed by your `ScriptProcessor` *before* you nulled it out.

Best bet is probably to throw a gain node into the path and just mute it on-demand.

Comment: Yah, that seems to be the issue I'm running into. I was hoping there was an easy way to clear out the buffer before before setting the call back to `null`, but I have not found one.

Comment: Well, you could call `stop()` on your `audioBufferSourceNode`. The `scriptProcessor` isn't really intended to be used as a mechanism for starting and stopping playback. If for some reason it's imperative that you use it that way, I guess you could reduce the `bufferSize` to cut down the amount of overhang after you null out `onaudioprocess`.