# How can I stop/pause a WebAudio ScriptProcessor node?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, web-audio-api, scriptprocessor

I can generate sounds using only createJavaScriptNode(...) on my HTML5 app. I need to generate white noise on the fly. The issue that I am having is that I can not stop/pause the generation for example setting null to the processor or the context.

I have seen this post: [How can I stop a Web Audio Script Processor and clear the buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648819/how-can-i-stop-a-web-audio-script-processor-and-clear-the-buffer) and I was wondering if there is a better solution than setting zero to a gain Node.

Do I have to worry about leaving the processor running if I don't need it? I wouldn't like to have "ghosts" in my code. It would be great if I can null the objects that I won't use anymore.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `ScriptProcessorNode`, since `JavaScriptAudioNode` is deprecated. Disconnecting the node from the graph should cause `onprocess` to no longer be called back.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should EXPLICITLY remove the onaudioprocess event handler from the object; otherwise it may not get garbage collected.

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: It doesn't. It only generates a different sound; almost the same that I had but in a lower frequency...  The guy from the question I mentioned above had the same troubles trying to set that to null.

Comment: oh.  you have to disconnect it too; otherwise it's continuing to use the same old buffer, just not firing the event.

Comment: BTW, it's a lot cheaper computationally and nearly as mathematically valid to just fill a short (e.g. 2-second) AudioBuffer with noise and loop it as a BufferSourceNode to generate white noise.